# Sharing a folder of files using iCloud Drive single-file sharing

Tags: icloud, sharing

With recent changes in macOS [High Sierra](https://www.apple.com/macos/high-sierra/) it is now possible to share individual files out of [iCloud Drive](https://www.apple.com/icloud/icloud-drive/), but no option to share an entire folder and its containing files.

**Q: Is there a workaround that would allow sharing an iCloud Drive folder** by leveraging the sharing of a single file?

Options that come into mind are archives (like ZIP) and disk images (Disk Utility).  The downsides of these solutions are that they need to be opened/mounted before use.

Please note: Any solution must be based on iCloud Drive. The intention is to specifically not use Dropbox and other third-party software or cloud services.

Comment: I would recommend automounting disk images